# How to check if a value is within multiple range of numbers

Tags: jquery

I am building a quiz, now is on the result part, which I need to show different result language based on the point user get. I know my code is not right, but that is all I know how to put together. The language is based on 3 range:
0-4: Keep study
5-7: Good
8-9: Excellent

```js
if (numCorrect > 0 && numCorrect <= 4){
          alert(+ numCorrect + "Keep studying.")
        }else{
          if (numCorrect > 5){
            alert(+ numCorrect + "Good Keep on learning!")
          }else{
            alert(+ numCorrect + "Excellent!")
          }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will be something like this:

```
function ShowResult(numCorrect){
   if(numCorrect != undefined)
   {
      if(numCorrect >= 0 && numCorrect < 5) {
          alert("Your message for low score")
      }
      else if(numCorrect >= 5 && numCorrect < 8) {
          alert("Your message for average score")
      }
      else { 
         alert("Your message for highscore")
      }
   }
}
```

Anyway there are better ways to handle that kind of things, have a dictionary already set up with the scores and also look for some nice tooltips, i've used toastr.js for example to have a nice impact, and you can change colors and stuff

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use else as your ranges are unique, they don't overlap.

So a simple series of `if` statements will do

```
if (numCorrect > 0 && numCorrect <= 4){
    alert(+ numCorrect + "Keep studying.")
}
if (numCorrect >= 5 && numCorrect <= 7){
    alert(+ numCorrect + "Good Keep on learning!")
}
if (numCorrect >= 8 && numCorrect <= 9){
    alert(+ numCorrect + "Excellent!")
}
// you could have an "else" here to catch any other value
```